# History.pushstate() in IE9 not working correctly

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pushstate, history.js

I want to change the whole link of my browser without reloading the page.

I tried to use

`window.history.pushState('Object', 'title', new_url);`

It works in firefox, chrome, IE11 but I need this to work with IE9.

So, I tried with [History.js](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fbrowserstate%2Fhistory.js&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHSI-vcUIBXoCnoN7oKCCyZwmTd0w) like this:

`History.pushState('Object', 'title', new_url) ;`

but in IE9 the new page url is concatinated with the old one, but I want it to be totally replaced!

Comment: it gives the same result..

Comment: what is your new_url?

Comment: For exemple the old link is : mon_site.com/produit/1/prod1.html and the  new_url = 'mon_site.com/produit/2/prod_new.html'

Answer (score 0):

Try your new_url with an absolute path. like `/prodult/2/prod_new.html` and note that pushState is not supported in IE9